# I enabled Google Cloud-Print but what can I do with it now on my phone?

Tags: cloud, printing

According to the page http://www.google.com/support/cloudprint/, I should now be able to print gmail mails :

**Answer taken from this page:**

*How do I print to my Google Cloud Printer?*

*+ The steps you take to print will vary from application to application.*

*- On Chrome notebooks, ...*

**- On Gmail and Google Docs for mobile, click the menu in the top right corner and select Print.**

Notice the `click the menu in the top right corner and select Print`.

I don't see such a button or looking at the wrong place.

**UPDATE - ADDITION**

Because I don't think this should qualify as a new question: I want to add this to my original: **what native Android applications support Google Cloud-Print ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not find this setting in Android's Gmail app, but on the Gmail mobile site (accessed via Browser) it's here:

[image: Gmail Print]

Comment: thanks for the clarification. This works. Pity you can't print from the Android Gmail application though.

Comment: Give them some time.  I bet it will come to the apps soon enough.